# ASP.NET C# SignalR Stream to Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, stream, signalr

I've got a couple SignalR basic demos working locally (chat, etc.) and I understand pushing to the server then having it broadcast to all connected clients.

My question is how might I utilize SignalR to "stream" data to the client.  For example, seen examples in NodeJS/Socket.IO utilizing Twitters streaming API.

Are there any SignalR streaming examples out there?  How might this work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at the samples in the SignalR.Samples project. There's a streaming sample in there.

Server side connection:

```
namespace SignalR.Samples.Streaming
{
    public class Streaming : PersistentConnection
    {
    }
}
```

Code that generates the stream

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
{
    var connection = Connection.GetConnection<Streaming.Streaming>();
    while (true)
    {
        connection.Broadcast(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
});
```

Client Side Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.signalR.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var connection = $.connection('Streaming.ashx');

            connection.received(function (data) {
                $('#messages').append('<li>' + data + '</li>');
            });

            connection.start();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="messages">
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is ok if you're broadcasting to all clients. But what if you wanted to push to specific clients the result of a background work? That's my current scenario... Thanks.

Comment: Keep a list of connection ids stored somewhere and send it to specific clients.

Comment: additional to this scenario, how to you stream from a connected client towards the hub?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use SignalR to tell the client to start a download over HTTP the old fashioned way? Or are you using `Stream` in a different way in terms of .NET?

If you just mean broadcasting external events, there is nothing that says that one of the clients can't be some other service that is sending in interesting data events to relay.